# Sitecore Sustaining Support

Tags: support

From 1 Jan 2023 Sitecore 8.2 will be under **Sustaining Support**

So what does that mean, what is covered by Sitecore, and what limitations/blockers it may bring in this type of support?

What would happen to the website when Sitecore stops supporting this version

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Sitecore, here is what you will get under this.

**Sustaining Support Phase**

These are products or product versions that are no longer eligible to be Extended Support products. In rare situations when customers are not able to migrate to the latest product versions before the products are no longer eligible to be Extended Support products, Sitecore provides Sustaining Support as a stop-gap solution for getting limited assistance with production issues and access to online documentation.

For detail information, follow this article.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0463549

And there are some notes given for all the support states. So according to Sitecore, assistance with product version upgrades is only provided when applying official version upgrade instructions and **the Sitecore version being upgraded from is in the Mainstream, Extended, or Sustaining support state, while the version being upgraded to is in the Mainstream support state**.

For more details follow this article.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0641167

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the second part to this question should be a new question, but it does relate so I'll answer it here:

> What would happen to the website when Sitecore stops supporting this version

Absolutely nothing, the website will still work just fine, its likely that you will be running on premises or PaaS for products that are this old, Sitecore doesn't own any of the resources for hosting, so you would just keep them running as before. BUT - as mentioned above, you will not be able to get full access to support in the event that you have issues with your site.